# Passar o value de 2 <select> utilizando jQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Tenho um `option select` que ao selecionar uma opção ele vai no BD e retorna o valor para um outro `option select`, funciona perfeitamente.

index com o `option select`:

```
<?php
require './conexao.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Atualizando combos com jquery</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#funcao').change(function () {
                    $('#tipo').load('listaFuncoes.php?funcao=' + $('#funcao').val());
                }).change();
            });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Atualizando combos com jquery</h1>
            <label>Função:</label>
            <select name="funcao" id="funcao">
                <option value="">selecione</option>
                <?php
                $rs = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM funcao ORDER BY nome");
                for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($rs); $i++) {
                    $linha_funcao = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?= $linha_funcao[0] ?>"><?php echo $linha_funcao[1] ?></option>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <br /><br />
            <div id="tipo">
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

e o meu `listaFuncoes.php` onde é alimentado com o resultado do 1º `option`:

```
<?php
require './conexao.php';

$id_estado = $_GET['funcao'];

$select_func = "SELECT DISTINCT tp.idfuncao, tpd.id ,tpd.descricao "
        . "FROM tipos_prova tp "
        . "INNER JOIN tipos_prova_descricao tpd ON tpd.idDescricao = tp.desctipoprova "
        . "WHERE tp.idfuncao = '$id_estado' "
        . "ORDER BY tpd.descricao";
$rs = mysqli_query($conexao, $select_func); 

echo "<select class='custom-select mb-3' name='tipo' required>
        <option value=''>selecione</option>";
for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($rs); $i++) {
    $linha_funcao = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
    ?>
    <option value="<?= $linha_funcao[0] ?>"><?php echo $linha_funcao[2] ?></option>
    <?php
}
echo "</select>";
```

Ai vem o problema, agora eu preciso de um 3º `option select` e que receba os valores passados do 1º e do 2º `option select` depois que escolher a opção do 2º `option`, como resolver?

Ex:
1º option passa value=1.
2º option passa value=3.
e no 3º option preciso desses 2 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A melhor opção para resolver seu problema é utilizando JavaScript.

Acrescente um ID em cada um de seus select, exemplo:

```
<select id="list1">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>

<select id="list2">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>

<select id="list3">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Agora para pegar o valores de cada select, é bem simples, você pode utilizar o jQuery, acrescente os scripts ao final do seu código.

Exemplo:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#list1').change(function(){
      alert(this.value); // valor que o usuário escolheu para a lista 1
    });

    $('#list2').change(function(){
      alert(this.value); // valor que o usuário escolheu para a lista 2
    });

    $('#list3').change(function(){
      alert(this.value); // valor que o usuário escolheu para a lista 3
    });
  });
</script>
```

Só tenha atenção para não importar a biblioteca do jQuery mais de uma vez, se você já tem o jQuery não precisa importar novamente.

Comment: Não resolveria, pois preciso que envie o value do 1º select junto ao 2º select, tipo busca de Pais/Estado/Cidade. ele vai pegar a cidade do estado daquele determinado pais.

Comment: Você consegue atribuir a uma variável fora do escopo os valores, pode ser até mesmo um objeto, algo como 'const location = { select1: 'valor3', select2: 'valor2', select3: 'valor3' }', e o seu this.value de cada chage vai setar no valor da propriedade correspondente do objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Crie arquivos de callback para cada consulta no banco de dados e faça as chamadas via ajax, o que vai gerar uma reação em cadeia e alterar todas as selects subsequentes.

Isso também facilita muito a manutenção do seu código.

Vou utilizar o exemplo do Pais/Estado/Cidade e seguir esta hierarquia.

Dentro da index, deixe os selects vazio, porém com nome e id definidos. Quem vai popular esses selects é o js com as informações que o php vai retornar para ele via json.

index.php

```
<body>

<select name="pais" id="pais"></select>
<select name="estado" id="estado"></select>
<select name="cidade" id="cidade"></select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="popularSelects.js"></script>
<script src="retornarPais.php?callback=retornarPais"></script>
```

Agora é só escrever os arquivos de busca. 
retornarPais.php - Este é pré-carregado na index e retorna todos os países da tabela

```
require_once "conexao.php";

$callback = isset($_GET['callback']) ?  $_GET['callback'] : false;
$query = "SELECT paisId, pais FROM pais";
$paises = mysqli_query($conecta,$query);
$retorno = array();
while($linha = mysqli_fetch_object($paises))
{
    $retorno[] = $linha;
}   
echo ($callback ? $callback . '(' : '') . json_encode($retorno) . ($callback? ')' : '');

mysqli_close($conecta);
```

retornarEstado.php - Chamado sempre que houver mudança no pais.

```
require_once "conexao.php";

$callback = isset($_GET['callback']) ?  $_GET['callback'] : false;
if(isset($_GET['paisId'])) 
{
    $paisID = $_GET['paisId'];
}
else
{
    $paisID = 1;
}
$query  = "SELECT estadoId, estado FROM estados ";
$query .= "WHERE paisId = {$paisID}";
$estados = mysqli_query($conecta,$query);
$retorno = array();
while($linha = mysqli_fetch_object($estados))
{
    $retorno[] = $linha;
}   
echo json_encode($retorno);

mysqli_close($conecta);
```

retornarCidade.php - Sempre que mudar o estado

```
require_once "conexao.php";

$callback = isset($_GET['callback']) ?  $_GET['callback'] : false;
if(isset($_GET['paisId']) && isset($_GET['estadoId'])) 
{
    $paisID = $_GET['paisId'];
    $estadoID = $_GET['estadoId'];
}
else
{
    $paisID = 1;
    $estadoID = 1;
}
$query  = "SELECT cidadeId, cidade FROM cidades ";
$query .= "WHERE paisId = {$paisID} AND estadoId = {$estadoID}";
$cidades = mysqli_query($conecta,$query);
$retorno = array();
while($linha = mysqli_fetch_object($cidades))
{
    $retorno[] = $linha;
}   
echo json_encode($retorno);

mysqli_close($conecta);
```

popularSelects.js

```
function retornarPais(data)           
{
    var pais = "";
    $pais_id = $("#pais").val();
    $.each(data, function(chave, valor){
        if ($pais_id == valor.paisId)
        {
            pais += '<option value="' + valor.paisId + '" selected>' + valor.pais + '</option>';
        }
        else
        {
            pais += '<option value="' + valor.paisId + '">' + valor.pais + '</option>';
        }
    });
    $("#pais").html(pais);
}
function carregarEstados()                  
{
    var pais_id = $('#pais').val();

    $.ajax ({
        type:"GET",
        data:"paisId=" + pais_id,
        url:"retornarEstados.php",
        async: false

    }).done(function(data){
        var estado = "";
        $estado_id = $("#estado").val();
        $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(chave, valor){
            if ($estado_id == valor.estadoId)
            {
                estado += '<option value="' + valor.estadoId + '" selected>' + valor.estado + '</option>';
            }
            else
            {
                estado += '<option value="' + valor.estadoId + '">' + valor.estado + '</option>';
            }
        });
        $("#estado").html(estado);
    });
}

function carregarCidades()                  
{
    var pais_id = $('#pais').val();
    var estado_id = $('#estado').val();

    $.ajax ({
        type:"GET",
        data:"paisId=" + pais_id + "&estadoId=" + estado_id,
        url:"retornarCidades.php",
        async: false

    }).done(function(data){
        var cidade = "";
        $cidade_id = $("#estado").val();
        $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(chave, valor){
            if ($cidade_id == valor.cidadeId)
            {
                cidade += '<option value="' + valor.cidadeId + '" selected>' + valor.cidade + '</option>';
            }
            else
            {
                cidade += '<option value="' + valor.cidadeId + '">' + valor.cidade + '</option>';
            }
        });
        $("#cidade").html(cidade);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    carregarEstados();
    carregarCidades();
});
$("#pais").change(function()
{
    carregarEstados();
    carregarCidades();
});

$("#estado").change(function()
{
    carregarCidades();
});
```

Eu utilizei exemplos bem simples para ficar mais fácil a leitura do código. Mas dentro dos arquivos de retorno você pode aumentar a complexidade das querys sem problemas.

Comment: Entendi @vaz fica ótimo também.